# Accessing files located on the file server from the DMZ

Tags: iis, asp.net, file-server, dmz

I need to set in place a new ASP.NET MVC solution where authenticated users can download files (originally located on the internal network). For security reasons, accessing internal network from the DMZ is not recommended so I think of a way to 'copy' these files from the internal network to the DMZ once a day as described by the diagram below.

[image]

**A.**  Files and folders are managed by someone connected with a computer inside the internal network.

**B.**  Once a day files and folders are copied into the DMZ. These files are never copied back to the internal network.

**C.**  Authorized users connect through internet to an ASP.NET MVC application. This application display lists of filenames filtered by folder names. Users can click filenames to download it.

**Is this a good approach?** Please note that files in question are not critical and can live inside the DMZ.

- If this is a good approach, what is the best way to copy files and folders from the INTERNAL NETWORK to the DMZ?
- If not, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In the broad strokes, yes, what you want to do is "push" the files from the internal network to the DMZ (a session initiated from a computer on the internal network), rather than "pull" the files to the DMZ from the internal network (a session initiated from a computer on the DMZ network).  This is the way the default rules on a lot of [hardware] firewalls are configured - traffic is permitted *from* more secure networks *to* less secure networks, but not the other way around, in general:

> Internal -> DMZ -> external

You probably don't even have to limit the file transfers to once a day, so long as the DMZ is not allowed to initiate sessions into the internal network, there's no appreciable security threat from allowing continuous/real-time file "synchronization" from internal to DMZ.  Your only real restriction would be not using a true synchronization or replication technology which requires communication from both sides (so something like DFS-R would probably not be a good choice). Even something as simple as a [robocopy /MIR job](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) running on the internal server sounds like it would work for your purposes.

Comment: very instructive answer for me, thanks for this. I'll first analyse the suggested solution. Please note your `MIR job` target link is the same as `robocopy` target link (maybe a mistake from you).

Comment: @Bronzato That's just a link to the ss64.org page on robocopy.  It lists all the options (including the /MIR option) and gives some examples.  So, just a link to the robocopy documentation, not intended to be a link to a guide on robocopy /MIR, specifically... if such a specific guide even exists.